# Recommend me a good CPU for this motherboard with GPU on board

Tags: ryzen

The mobo is

Motherboard Colorful A320M-K PRO (Soket Am4 DDR4 )

The mobo cannot handle Ryzen 5. But can handle Ryzen 3.

The list of cost effective CPU is https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_value_available.html

The CPU will not be used to play games. So will not have video card.

Or recommend me a video card that can handle normal 4k windows. Just basic cheap video card that's compatible.

Would be great if we can know why AM4 mobo does not necessarily able to run Ryzen 5. How should we know that? The slot is the same AM4

Answer (score 0):

It should support Ryzen 5, the Colourful website doesn't specify (I don't think, from a quick look), and other sources say it shouldn't matter. If you want to test it, try a Ryzen 5 5500 or 5600G. If not, a Ryzen 3 4100 or 4300G will be plenty if you are not playing games. In terms of GPU, the Ryzen CPUs with a 'G' at the end have integrated graphics, and this will be fine for normal running of Windows. If you want a GPU, maybe the Nvidia GeForce 1030 (get one with a fan) or the Nvidia GeForce GT 1050.

Answer (score 0):

With this motherboard, you are limited to 65W TDP processors. The fastest of them is:

> AMD Ryzen 7 5700X (3.4 GHz / 4.6 GHz) Processor 8-Core 16-Threads
> socket AM4 GameCache 36 MB 7 nm TDP 65W

For a given range, usually I would go to the "fastest" because the `"tech package or range of usage or upgrade" / price` factor is the highest. If in the end you are limited by price, you can pick any CPU by decrease its reference number (eg., 5600, etc). All of 5000 CPUs give you great TCO (~good energy efficiency), thanks to recent manufacturing process; hence I do not recommend to go for previous generations.